# TaskList command hangs up while using in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I am trying to use **tasklist.exe** utility using a batch script to find weather a process is running on remote server or not

I am using following command,

```
tasklist /s 192.168.1.246 /u myusername /p mypassword /FI " IMAGENAME eq oracle.EXE" > temp.txt
```

When I try to execute the above command directly from command prompt,it executes and gives the desired output

```
Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
oracle.exe                    4988 Console                    0  5,121,392 K
```

But when the same command is placed in a batch file, the command promt windows hangs with cursor blinking.

Please help me with this issue.

Regards

Comment: What non-alphanumeric characters does your password contain?  Are there any symbols that might be interfering?

Comment: Password here is Project@123, is that responsibile for hang up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the name of your batch `tasklist.bat` to `anothername.bat` or add `.exe` in the line of code in: `tasklist.exe /s 192.168...`

Comment: Thanks walid. Adding .exe to the tasklist worked. What could be the reason for not running when using only tasklist since I have used in other commands?

Comment: @Suvojit: your script not tunning tasklist.exe but it running it self in infinite loop

Comment: I see...but y so ? because I have used wmic command in the same way without writting wmic.exe ...